# creating signed uninstaller using embedded signing rather than separate uninstaller script

Tags: nsis

In order to create a signed uninstaller, I cannot create this using the usual NSIS `WriteUninstaller` command, because the usually script will create the uninstaller and embed it inside the installer, so there is no chance to sign the uninstaller.  For details please see https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-245688.html.

This means that I would have to create a separate uninstaller script, sign that, and then embed it in the installer using a normal File command.  This works in deleting the files; however, since the uninstaller executable that is running, it cannot delete itself, and leaves the `uninstaller.exe` and the `MyApp` directory behind.  Here is my uninstaller script:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Sections.nsh"
    
;Include Modern UI
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MAJOR_VERSION "1" 
!define MINOR_VERSION "2" 
!define PATCH_VERSION "3" 
!define BUILD_VERSION "4" 
    
!define APP_COPYRIGHT "MyApp © MyCompany 2021"
!define COMPANY_NAME "MyCompany"
!define FLEX_LM "FlexLM"        
!define FLEX_DIR "FlexSMyApp"            
!define LANG_ENGLSH "English" 
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${PATCH_VERSION}.${BUILD_VERSION}"
!define SETUP_NAME "MyAppSetup.exe"

BrandingText "MyCompany"

OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME}"

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\$PRODUCT_NAME" ""
ShowInstDetails hide
ShowUnInstDetails hide

SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
SetCompressorDictSize 12

Var MyAppInstallDir
Var FlexLmInstallDir

;Request application privileges for Windows 
RequestExecutionLevel admin

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "MyAppLicense.txt"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesCheck
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ComponentsLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS   
 
## This is the title on the MyApp Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A)"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Please choose the folder in which to install MyApp."
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
 
## This is the title on the FlexLM Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B)"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Please choose the folder in which to install FlexLM."
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE DeleteSectionsINI
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;Languages

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------

LangString NoSectionsSelected ${LANG_ENGLSH} "You haven't selected any sections!"

LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${PRODUCT_NAME} in the following folder..."
LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${FLEX_LM} in the following folder..."

;--------------------------------
; Settings
 
!define PROG1_InstDir    "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
!define PROG1_StartIndex ${SEC1}
!define PROG1_EndIndex   ${SEC1}
 
!define PROG2_InstDir "C:\${FLEX_DIR}"
!define PROG2_StartIndex ${SEC3}
!define PROG2_EndIndex   ${SEC3}

;--------------------------------
; Function
; StrContains
; This function does a case sensitive searches for an occurrence of a substring in a string. 
; It returns the substring if it is found. 
; Otherwise it returns null(""). 
; Written by kenglish_hi
; Adapted from StrReplace written by dandaman32
 
 
Var STR_HAYSTACK
Var STR_NEEDLE
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4
Var STR_RETURN_VAR
 
Function StrContains
  Exch $STR_NEEDLE
  Exch 1
  Exch $STR_HAYSTACK
  ; Uncomment to debug
  ;MessageBox MB_OK 'STR_NEEDLE = $STR_NEEDLE STR_HAYSTACK = $STR_HAYSTACK '
    StrCpy $STR_RETURN_VAR ""
    StrCpy $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 -1
    StrLen $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2 $STR_NEEDLE
    StrLen $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4 $STR_HAYSTACK
    loop:
      IntOp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 + 1
      StrCpy $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3 $STR_HAYSTACK $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1
      StrCmp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3 $STR_NEEDLE found
      StrCmp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4 done
      Goto loop
    found:
      StrCpy $STR_RETURN_VAR $STR_NEEDLE
      Goto done
    done:
   Pop $STR_NEEDLE ;Prevent "invalid opcode" errors and keep the
   Exch $STR_RETURN_VAR  
FunctionEnd
 
!macro _StrContainsConstructor OUT NEEDLE HAYSTACK
  Push `${HAYSTACK}`
  Push `${NEEDLE}`
  Call StrContains
  Pop `${OUT}`
!macroend
 
!define StrContains '!insertmacro "_StrContainsConstructor"'

;--------------------------------
; Start sections

Section "MyApp" SEC1
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "MyApp" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundMyApp
      StrCpy $MyAppInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
      Goto doneMyApp
    notfoundMyApp:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find MyApp string'
    doneMyApp:  

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'    

    ##All the files in Group 1 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    File MyApp.exe
    File ReleaseNotes.txt
    File MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
    File MyAppLicense.txt  
  
    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$InstDir\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 

    # Add application to registry  
    ClearErrors
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Company Name' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Version' "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'AppID' "{A0E84732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-462B8DF92DCD}"
 
    # Add program to Add/Remove programs 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayIcon" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "AppID" "{A0E84732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-462B8DF92DCD}"              
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayName" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"                      
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "Publisher" "${COMPANY_NAME}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe$\""

!ifndef INNER
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
 
  ; this packages the signed uninstaller
 
  File $%TEMP%\uninstaller.exe
!endif        
    doneFlex:   

  # messagebox mb_ok sec1
SectionEnd

Section "FlexLM" SEC3
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC3 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"

    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "Pro" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundMyApp
      StrCpy $MyAppInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
      Goto doneMyApp
    notfoundMyApp:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find MyApp string'

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'
    doneFlex:     

    ##All the files in Group 2 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
    File installs.exe
    File lmdown.exe
    File lmflex.exe
    
    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
    doneMyApp: 

  # messagebox mb_ok sec3
 
SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  ;Language strings
  LangString DESC_SecMyApp ${LANG_ENGLISH} "MyAppTM software is an easy-to-use suite of tools."
  LangString DESC_SecFlexLM ${LANG_ENGLISH} "FlexSMyApp contains all the files necessary to implement the FlexLM license server."

  ;Assign language strings to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN    
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC1} $(DESC_SecMyApp)
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC3} $(DESC_SecFlexLM)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

; ...
 
Function .onInit
!ifdef INNER
 
  ; If INNER is defined, then we aren't supposed to do anything except write out
  ; the uninstaller.  This is better than processing a command line option as it means
  ; this entire code path is not present in the final (real) installer.
  SetSilent silent
  WriteUninstaller "$%TEMP%\uninstaller.exe"
  Quit  ; just bail out quickly when running the "inner" installer
!endif
      
  ## Create $PLUGINSDIR 
  InitPluginsDir

  SetOutPath $TEMP
  File /oname=spltmp.bmp "MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp"

  splash::show 2000 $TEMP\spltmp

  Pop $0 ; $0 has '1' if the user closed the splash screen early,
  ; '0' if everything closed normally, and '-1' if some error occurred.

  Delete $TEMP\spltmp.bmp  
FunctionEnd
 
; ...
 
Section "Files" ; or whatever
 
; ...
 
  ; where you would normally put WriteUninstaller ${INSTDIR}\uninstaller.exe put instead:
 
;!ifndef INNER
    ;  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
 
  ; this packages the signed uninstaller
 
    ;  File $%TEMP%\uninstaller.exe
;!endif
 
; ...
SectionEnd
 
!ifdef INNER
Section "Uninstall"  

  ; your normal uninstaller section or sections (they're not needed in the "outer"
  ; installer and will just cause warnings because there is no WriteUninstaller command)
  # Always delete uninstaller first
  Delete $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
 
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for MyApp
  Delete $INSTDIR\config.dat
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyApp.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyAppLicense.txt
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp.lnk"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Modern UI Test"     
        
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for FlexLM
  Delete $INSTDIR\installs.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmborrow.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmflex.exe

  # Delete the MyApp and FlexLM directories
  RMDir $INSTDIR

SectionEnd
!endif

;--------------------------------
; Please don`t modify below here unless you`re a NSIS 'wiz-kid'
 
## Also if no sections are selected, warn the user!
Function ComponentsLeave
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 Call IsPROG1Selected
  Pop $R0
 Call IsPROG2Selected
  Pop $R1
 StrCmp $R0 1 End
 StrCmp $R1 1 End
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
 MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "$(NoSectionsSelected)"
 Abort
 
End:
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
    
Function IsPROG1Selected
Push $R0

 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex} # Group 1 start
 
   SectionGetFlags 0 $R0            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R0 1
 
Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
 
Function IsPROG2Selected
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R1 ${PROG2_StartIndex}    # Group 2 start
 
   IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1
   SectionGetFlags 1 $R1            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R1 $R1 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R1 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R1 1
 
Exch $R1
FunctionEnd

## Here we are selecting first sections to install
## by unselecting all the others!
Function SelectFilesA
  ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC1}
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
  ${Else}  
      Abort
  ${EndIf}  
 
 # If user clicks Back now, we will know to reselect Group 2`s sections for
 # Components page
 StrCpy $IfBack 1
 
 # We need to save the state of the Group 2 Sections
 # for the next InstFiles page
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG2_StartIndex} # Group 2 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;   SectionGetFlags $R0 $R1                 # Get section flags
;    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\sections.ini" Sections $R0 $R1 # Save state
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0               # Then unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG2_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
 # Don`t install prog 1?
 Call IsPROG1Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG1_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG1_InstDir}"
 
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
 
## Here we need to unselect all Group 1 sections
## and then re-select those in Group 2 (that the user had selected on
## Components page)
Function SelectFilesB
  ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC3}
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
  ${Else}  
      Abort
  ${EndIf} 

Push $R0
;Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex}    # Group 1 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0       # Unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG1_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
; Call ResetFiles
 
 # Don't install prog 2?
 Call IsPROG2Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG2_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG2_InstDir}"
 
;Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks [@Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders), I had somehow deleted the `SelectFilesCheck` by mistake.  Now, if I use this code:

```
!ifdef INNER
  !echo "Inner invocation"                  ; just to see what's going on
  OutFile "$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe"       ; not really important where this is
  SetCompress off                           ; for speed
!else
  !echo "Outer invocation"
 
  ; Call makensis again against current file, defining INNER.  This writes an installer for us which, when
  ; it is invoked, will just write the uninstaller to some location, and then exit.
 
  !makensis '/DINNER "${__FILE__}"' = 0
 
  ; So now run that installer we just created as %TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe.  Since it
  ; calls quit the return value isn't zero.
 
  !system 'set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker&"$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe"' = 2
 
  ; That will have written an uninstaller binary for us.  Now we sign it with your
  ; favorite code signing tool. 
  nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /c "SMyApp-SignTool.bat $%TEMP%\uninstaller.exe"'
 
  ; Good.  Now we can carry on writing the real installer.
 
  OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
  SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
!endif
 
Section "MyApp" SEC1

    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "MyApp" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundMyApp
      StrCpy $QiProInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 QiProInstallDir is $QiProInstallDir"
      Goto doneMyApp
    notfoundMyApp:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find MyApp string'
    doneMyApp:  

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'

    ##All the files in Group 1 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    # specify files to go in output path
    File config.dat
    File MyApp.exe
    File ReleaseNotes.txt
    File MyApp_LandingPage_114.bmp
    File MyAppLicense.txt  
  
    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$InstDir\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 

    # Add application to registry  
    ClearErrors
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Contact' "https://www.mycompany.com/contact"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Company Name' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'DisplayName' "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'DisplayVersion' "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'AppID' "{K2C40732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-464L9DF92DCD}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'HelpLink' "http://www.mycompany.com/myapp/HelpDocs/index.htm"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'URLInfoAbout' "https://www.mycompany.com/myapp"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'InstallLocation' "$MyAppInstallDir"    
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Publisher' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
 
    # Add program to Add/Remove programs 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "DisplayIcon" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "AppID" "{K2C40732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-464L9DF92DCD}"              
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "DisplayName" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"               
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"                        
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "Publisher" "${COMPANY_NAME}"               
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe$\"" 
    
    # Delete splash page image
    Delete $INSTDIR\MyApp_LandingPage_114.bmp           

!ifndef INNER
  ;SetOutPath $INSTDIR
 
  ; this packages the signed uninstaller
 
  File $%TEMP%\uninstaller.exe
!endif
```

Then I get these errors:

```
!makensis: returned 0
!system: "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker&"C:\Users\moorer\AppData\Local\Temp\tempinstaller.exe""
!system: returned 2
Error: Can't add entry, no section or function is open!
Error in script "C:\Project\MsiPackaging\Installer\MyAppInstaller.nsi" on line 169 -- aborting creation process
```

But if I try to put it in a section like this:

```
;--------------------------------
; Start sections
 

Section "MyApp" SEC1
!ifdef INNER
  !echo "Inner invocation"                  ; just to see what's going on
  OutFile "$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe"       ; not really important where this is
  SetCompress off                           ; for speed
!else
  !echo "Outer invocation"
 
  ; Call makensis again against current file, defining INNER.  This writes an installer for us which, when
  ; it is invoked, will just write the uninstaller to some location, and then exit.
 
  !makensis '/DINNER "${__FILE__}"' = 0
 
  ; So now run that installer we just created as %TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe.  Since it
  ; calls quit the return value isn't zero.
 
  !system 'set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker&"$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe"' = 2
 
  ; That will have written an uninstaller binary for us.  Now we sign it with your
  ; favorite code signing tool. 
  nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /c "SQI-SignTool.bat $%TEMP%\uninstaller.exe"'
 
  ; Good.  Now we can carry on writing the real installer.
 
  OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
  SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
!endif
    
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "MyApp" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundQI
      StrCpy $QiProInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 QiProInstallDir is $QiProInstallDir"
      Goto doneQI
    notfoundQI:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find QI string'
    doneQI: 

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'

    ##All the files in Group 1 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    # specify files to go in output path
    File config.dat
    File MyApp.exe
    File ReleaseNotes.txt
    File MyApp_LandingPage_114.bmp
    File MyAppLicense.txt  
  
    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$InstDir\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 

    # Add application to registry  
    ClearErrors
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Contact' "https://www.mycompany.com/contact"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Company Name' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'DisplayName' "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'DisplayVersion' "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'AppID' "{K2C40732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-464L9DF92DCD}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'HelpLink' "http://www.mycompany.com/myapp/HelpDocs/index.htm"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'URLInfoAbout' "https://www.mycompany.com/myapp"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'InstallLocation' "$MyAppInstallDir"    
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Publisher' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
 
    # Add program to Add/Remove programs 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "DisplayIcon" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "AppID" "{K2C40732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-464L9DF92DCD}"              
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "DisplayName" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"               
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"                        
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "Publisher" "${COMPANY_NAME}"               
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe$\"" 

    # Delete splash page image
    Delete $INSTDIR\MyApp_LandingPage_114.bmp           

!ifndef INNER
  ;SetOutPath $INSTDIR
 
  ; this packages the signed uninstaller
 
  File $%TEMP%\uninstaller.exe
!endif

    doneFlex:   

  # messagebox mb_ok sec1
SectionEnd
```

Then I get this error:

```
Error: command OutFile not valid in Section
Error in script "MyAppInstaller.nsi" on line 157 -- aborting creation process
!makensis: returned 1, aborting
Error in script "C:\Projects\MsiPackaging\Installer\MyAppInstaller.nsi" on line 165 -- aborting creation process
```

Do you have any suggestions?  TIA.

Comment: Inspect the code from the wiki, you are just pasting things in the wrong places. There are 4 separate pieces of code inside !if... The first goes outside sections/functions, the rest are inside something.

Comment: In your edit, nsExec::ExecToStack is wrong, it needs to be !system to call signing batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing code from the Wiki does not use `StrCpy` at all, it must be from your `StrCpy $IfBack 1` line. Maybe you forgot `Var IfBack` above the function.

The [code from the wiki](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Signing_an_Uninstaller) should work but here is an alternative version:

```
#TODO: RequestExecutionLevel
#TODO: InstallDir
!include MUI2.nsh

!macro WriteSignedUninstaller Destination
!makensis '"/DGENRATINGUNINST=$%TEMP%\Uninst.exe" "${__FILE__}" "/XOutfile `$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe`"' = 0 ; Create fake installer
!system 'set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker&"$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe"' = 2 ; Run fake installer to generate the uninstaller
!system 'SIGNCODE <signing options> "$%TEMP%\Uninst.exe"' = 0 ; Change this line. As a demonstration, use !system 'echo Dummy >> "$%TEMP%\Uninst.exe"'
File "/oname=${Destination}" "$%TEMP%\Uninst.exe"
!macroend

!macro DeclareLanguages
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
!macroend


!ifndef GENRATINGUNINST
# Installer:
############
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro DeclareLanguages

Section
    SetOutPath $InstDir
    !insertmacro WriteSignedUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
    ; File MyApp.exe
SectionEnd

!else
# Uninstaller:
##############
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro DeclareLanguages

!verbose push 2
SilentInstall Silent
Section
WriteUninstaller "${GENRATINGUNINST}"
Quit
SectionEnd
!verbose pop

Section -Uninstall
    ; Delete "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
    Delete "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
    RMDir "$InstDir"
SectionEnd

!endif # EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, [@Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders).  In the end, I found this `SelfDel` plugin, which allows me to go with the separate installer and uninstaller scripts while still deleting the uninstaller:

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/SelfDel_plug-in

```
Name `SelfDel plug-in example`
OutFile Example.exe
XPStyle on

; Administrator privileges required.
RequestExecutionLevel admin

Page InstFiles

Section
  ;SelfDel::Del /RMDIR
  ;SelfDel::Del /REBOOT
  ;SelfDel::Del /SHUTDOWN
  SelfDel::Del
  SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd
```

**UPDATE:**

When I use use `SelfDel` it deletes the `uninstaller.exe` but does not delete the original app directory even if I use `SelfDel::Del /RMDIR` so I ended up going with [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders) answer above.