# SelfDel function removes uninstaller but is not removing app directory with NSIS

Tags: nsis

In order to sign both the installer and uninstaller, I have created a separate uninstaller script as suggested here: https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-245688.html.  Thus, the uninstaller script not using the `WriteUninstaller` way to create the uninstaller.

Please note that I am using the [SelfDel](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/SelfDel_plug-in) plug-in to delete the uninstaller, which works successfully; however, it does not actually delete the application install directory even though I am using the `/RMDIR` option:

```
Function .onInstSuccess
 
  ;SelfDel::Del /REBOOT
  ;SelfDel::Del /SHUTDOWN
  SelfDel::Del /RMDIR
  SelfDel::Del
  
  SetAutoClose true

FunctionEnd
```

Here is the full script for your reference.

```
!define APP_COPYRIGHT "MyApp © MyCompany 2021"
!define COMPANY_NAME "MyCompany"         
!define LANG_ENGLSH "English" 
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${PATCH_VERSION}.${BUILD_VERSION}"
!define SETUP_NAME "uninstaller.exe"

# define the name of the installer
OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
Icon "favicon.ico"
!define MUI_ICON "favicon.ico"

# define the directory to install to
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
 
# default section
Section
 
  # define the output path for this file
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for MyApp
  ReadRegStr $0 HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "InstallLocation"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  Delete $0\config.dat
  Delete $0\MyApp.exe
  Delete $0\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $0\MyApp_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $0\MyAppLicense.txt
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp.lnk"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Modern UI Test"   
SectionEnd

Function .onInstSuccess
 
  ;SelfDel::Del /REBOOT
  ;SelfDel::Del /SHUTDOWN
  SelfDel::Del /RMDIR
  SelfDel::Del
  
  SetAutoClose true

FunctionEnd
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get it to delete the app directory?  TIA.

Comment: Why are you calling the plug-in twice?

Comment: I would advice you to go back to the original method of generating a signed uninstaller that you sign with !system.

Comment: That is the ideal solution, but as I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108923/creating-signed-uninstaller-using-embedded-signing-rather-than-separate-uninstal, I am getting errors both when I try to keep the signing outside of a section and inside of a section.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The example here is only a partial script: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Signing_an_Uninstaller.  Do you happen to know of a complete example somewhere?  Is the top part of that example part of a function?  If so, then how do I call that function?

Comment: The script on that wiki page is not partial, it works as is (after changing the SIGNCODE parameters).

Comment: Okay, if I try to add that section to my install script, then why am I getting this compile error `Error: Can't add entry, no section or function is open!` as I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108923/creating-signed-uninstaller-using-embedded-signing-rather-than-separate-uninstal?

Comment: Clearly nsExec::ExecToStack you added to that code is not going to work

Comment: I changed my answer in your other question, try that code.

Comment: okay thx, I'll try to test it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

So I don't really know the SelfDel nsis plugin that well, but have you tried just restarting your machine after deleting your install-directory like so?

```
SelfDel::Del /RMDIR
SelfDel::Del

SelfDel::Del /REBOOT
;or just
Reboot
```

That might help.

Wish you all the best.

**Update**

Ok so you tried to Reboot.

I researched a little further on the topic and found the same problem, but without the SelfDel plugin: [How to solve "The directory is not empty" error when running rmdir command in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948189/how-to-solve-the-directory-is-not-empty-error-when-running-rmdir-command-in-a/22949687)

But maybe you could also try to remove the directory and all the files in the "normal NSIS way" like this:

```
RMDir /r $YOURDIR
```

Try this maybe it will work, and perhaps it's just some bug from the plugin.

The SourceForge site of the plugin says it's only testet on Windows 8, so if you are using it on Windows 10 there might be some bugs.

Read the note at the bottom of the SourceForge site: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/SelfDel_plug-in
They say that it is a Trojan Virus and I would recommend to stop using it.

I would seriously consider using another plugin that is testet for Windows 10.

Wish you all the best.

Comment: Yes, I had tried `SelfDel::Del /RMDIR` with and without the `/REBOOT` but it didn't remove the directory in both cases.